# Use Bing to geocode and Google maps api to display the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-maps-api-2, bing-maps

I have an application which is currently using the google map API. I like the maps much better, and I feel like you have more options with google maps. The problem is, Google maps has been very inaccurate when I give it an address to map, while Bing has been 100% on so far. I also like Bings Birds Eye view, but that's not as important. My question is, can I use the Bing API to take the address that I give it, return a longitude and latitude and then give that to my existing Google map to plot the point. If so, how? I looked on Bing Maps, and I couldn't find a good way to geocode an address. Below is my current google maps code

```
var map;
var directionsPanel;
var directions;

function initialize() {
  map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(41.1255275,-73.6964801), 15);
  directionsPanel = document.getElementById("route");
  directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
  directions.load("from: ADDRESS 1 to: ADDRESS 2 ");

          map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

}
```

I want to replace ADDRESS 2 with the longitude and latitude which Bing gets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the Bing Maps Ajax Control does not support Geocoding. You will need to use their web services: [SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250965.aspx) or [JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx) or [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250893.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

As Matt Phillips suggests, you should read the terms of service: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html

There is a restriction regarding combining different map services:

> ***Restrictions on your use:*** We do have some restrictions on your use of the service. You may not:
>
> ...
>
> - integrate the Bing Maps Platform or any of its content with any other mapping platform;

The Google terms of service are also quite strict and I'd imagine they'd have a similar restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should check out the [Bing Maps API licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/licensing.aspx) to see if thats really the road you want to take. If it is then I would suggest looking at the api to see how you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Bing Locations API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx).

Here is an article on how to [Find a Location by Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx).  You can then use the latitude and longitude to give to Google Maps.